# Psfrag Error: File ended while scanning use of @psfragb

Tags: pdftex, psfrag

I have a problem with the psfrag package in MacTeX. I am trying to replace the text “Quantity” in an EPS graphic with “Menge”, but it is not working. Here is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\def\\svgwidth{175pt}
\psfrag{Quantity}{Menge}
\input{meinegrafik.eps_tex}
\caption{Demand Elasticity}
\label{fig:my_graphic}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \@psfragb.
<inserted text>
\par
<*> psdfrag.tex
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
! Emergency stop.
<*> psdfrag.tex
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
1461 strings out of 476025
24902 string characters out of 5790018
1849388 words of memory out of 5000000
21951 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
512287 words of font info for 32 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
57i,2n,62p,202b,125s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: I can't test so I can only guess but a quick look to the documentation suggests that the picture should be included by `\includegraphics`, not `\input`.

Comment: @campa Thank's for your quick reply. \includegraphics doesen't work either. It seems there is a problem with the -shell-escape command. I use Texmaker and I'm still figuring out how to activate -shell-escape in my editor.

Comment: The fact that you do `\input{meinegrafik.eps_tex}` indicates that you have drawn the figure in inkscape, and saved is as a combined eps/latex pair. I did a quick test using a simple inkscape figure and your MWE code, and it works without problems. However, I am a bit confused with the error log you cited. That log mentions `psdfrag.tex`, which does not appear in your code, so I think I would want to know where that came from.